Proxy error: Unable to parse auth header from HTTP proxy: authentication type 'NTLM' not supported"
I am using a batch script to download files from an SFTP server over the Internet. The script is running on a VM which is behind a corporate proxy.
When I am logged in to the SFTP server via WinSCP, the script runs fine but when I am running the script by itself, I get the error: Proxy error: Unable to parse auth header from HTTP proxy:
authentication type 'NTLM' not supported"
What am I doing wrong?
Here is a snippet of the script:
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

$Source = "E:\somepath\"
$username = "someusername"
$password = "somep@ssw0rd"
$pair = "$($username):$($password)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "11.222.333.44"
    PortNumber = 5567
    UserName = "sftpusername"
    Password = "sftppassw0rd"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-ed25519 255 DHhI/5fErnTc1txlbYDeBkRuhWkIMJl6axQRj4t/Xjy"
}

$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyMethod", "3")
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyHost", "10.26.46.92")
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyPort", "8080")
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("Authorization", $basicAuthValue)

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Transfer files
    $session.GetFiles("/sftppath/"+$timestamp, $Source).Check()
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}

I tried passing the username and password instead of the authorization token but got the same issue.
I tried making this in Python using paramiko but getting stuck there as well.
Update 1: Removed as it is not required
Update 2: Removed as it is not required
Update 3: Here is the session log file generated using Session.SessionLogPath
. 

2024-07-21 19:30:01.290 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.290 WinSCP Version 5.21.1 (Build 12643 2022-06-24) (OS 10.0.17763 - Windows Server 2019 Standard)
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.290 Configuration: nul
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.290 Log level: Normal
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.290 Local account: somedomain\someuser
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.290 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.290 Process ID: 9272
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Ancestor processes: powershell, svchost, ...
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe" /xmllog="C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Temp\wscp2D1C.00216C05.tmp" /xmlgroups /xmllogrequired /nointeractiveinput /stdout /stdin /dotnet=5.21.1  /ini=nul /log="D:\Schedulers\Powershell\BSEScriptSession21072024.log"  /console /consoleinstance=_11548_31456487_964
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Time zone: Current: GMT+5:30 (India Standard Time), No DST
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Login time: 21 July 2024 19:30:01
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: Retrospectively logging previous script records:
> 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: option batch on
< 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: batch           on        
< 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: reconnecttime   120       
> 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: option confirm off
< 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: confirm         off       
> 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: option reconnecttime 120
< 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: reconnecttime   120       
> 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: open sftp://someusername:***@11.222.333.44:5567 -hostkey="ssh-ed25519 255 DHhI/5fErnTc1txlbYDeBkRuhWkIMJl6axQRj4t/Xjs" -timeout=15 -rawsettings ProxyMethod="3" ProxyHost="10.26.46.92" ProxyPort="8080" Authorization="Basic R0VQT1dBVVRPVUFUOklwcnVhbWNAMTIzNDU2"
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Session name: someusername@11.222.333.44 (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Host name: 11.222.333.44 (Port: 5567)
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 User name: someusername (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Tunnel: No
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Transfer Protocol: SFTP
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Disable Nagle: No
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Proxy: HTTP
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 HostName: 10.26.46.92 (Port: 8080); Username: ; Passwd: No
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Send buffer: 262144
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Compression: No
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Bypass authentication: No
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: Yes
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 GSSAPI: KEX: No; Forwarding: No; Libs: gssapi32,sspi,custom; Custom: 
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Ciphers: aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 KEX: ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Simple channel: Yes
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Shell: default
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 EOL: LF, UTF: Auto
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No; Exit code 1 is error: No
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 SFTP Bugs: Auto,Auto
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 SFTP Server: default
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 DST mode: Unix
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
< 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: Searching for host...
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Leaving host lookup to proxy of "11.222.333.44" (for SSH connection)
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Will use HTTP proxy at 10.26.46.92:8080 to connect to 11.222.333.44:5567
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Looking up host "10.26.46.92" for proxy
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Connecting to HTTP proxy at 10.26.46.92 port 8080
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Connecting to 10.26.46.92 port 8080
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Connected to 10.26.46.92
< 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Script: Connecting to host...
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.21.1
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Connected to 10.26.46.92
. 2024-07-21 19:30:01.305 Proxy error: Unable to parse auth header from HTTP proxy: authentication type 'NTLM' not supported
< 2024-07-21 19:30:01.321 Script: Proxy error: Unable to parse auth header from HTTP proxy: authentication type 'NTLM' not supported

Update 4: Here is the WinSCP log that is generated from Preference -> Logging:
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.367 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.367 WinSCP Version 5.21.1 (Build 12643 2022-06-24) (OS 10.0.17763 - Windows Server 2019 Standard)
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.367 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.367 Log level: Normal
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.367 Local account: somedomain\someuser
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.367 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.367 Process ID: 10388
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Ancestor processes: explorer, ...
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Time zone: Current: GMT+5:30 (India Standard Time), No DST
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Login time: 26 July 2024 00:36:16
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Session name: session (Site)
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Host name: 11.222.333.44 (Port: 5567)
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 User name: sftpusername (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Tunnel: No
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Transfer Protocol: SFTP (SCP)
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Disable Nagle: No
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Proxy: HTTP
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 HostName: 10.26.46.92 (Port: 8080); Username: someuser; Passwd: Yes
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Send buffer: 262144
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Compression: No
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Bypass authentication: No
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: Yes
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 GSSAPI: KEX: No; Forwarding: No; Libs: gssapi32,sspi,custom; Custom: 
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Ciphers: aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 KEX: ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Simple channel: Yes
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Shell: default
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 EOL: LF, UTF: Auto
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No; Exit code 1 is error: No
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 SFTP Bugs: Auto,Auto
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 SFTP Server: default
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Local directory: E:\somefolder, Remote directory: /dirname, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 DST mode: Unix
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.383 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.430 Leaving host lookup to proxy of "11.222.333.44" (for SSH connection)
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.430 Will use HTTP proxy at 10.26.46.92:8080 to connect to 11.222.333.44:5567
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.430 Looking up host "10.26.46.92" for proxy
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.430 Connecting to HTTP proxy at 10.26.46.92 port 8080
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.430 Connecting to 10.26.46.92 port 8080
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.430 Connected to 10.26.46.92
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.445 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.21.1
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.445 Connected to 10.26.46.92
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.461 Connected to remote host
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.461 Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.461 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.461 Have a known host key of type ssh-ed25519
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.477 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.617 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/rsa-sha2-512/rsa-sha2-256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.617 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.617 ssh-ed25519 255 SHA256:DHhI/5fErnTc1txlbYDeBkRuhWkIMJl6axQRj4t/Xjy
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.633 Host key matches cached key
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.633 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] outbound encryption
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.633 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 outbound MAC algorithm
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.633 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] inbound encryption
. 2024-07-26 00:36:16.633 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 inbound MAC algorithm
! 2024-07-26 00:36:16.649 Using username "sftpusername".
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.258 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.258 Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.258 Trying gssapi-with-mic...
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.258 Attempting GSSAPI authentication
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.352 GSSAPI authentication request refused
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.352 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.352 Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.477 Prompt (keyboard interactive, "SSH server authentication", <no instructions>, "Password: ")
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.477 Using stored password.
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.617 Prompt (keyboard interactive, "SSH server authentication", <no instructions>, <no prompt>)
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.617 Ignoring empty SSH server authentication request
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.649 Access granted
. 2024-07-26 00:36:18.649 Opening main session channel
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.055 Opened main channel
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.180 Started a shell/command
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.195 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.195 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.195 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2024-07-26 00:36:19.211 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 238, Number: -1
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Unknown server extension posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Supports statvfs@openssh.com extension version 2
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Unknown server extension fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Supports hardlink@openssh.com extension version 1
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Unknown server extension fsync@openssh.com="1"
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Unknown server extension lsetstat@openssh.com="1"
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Supports limits@openssh.com extension version 1
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Unknown server extension expand-path@openssh.com="1"
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Limiting packet size to OpenSSH sftp-server limit of 262148 bytes
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Changing directory to "/sftpusername".
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Getting real path for '/sftpusername'
> 2024-07-26 00:36:19.258 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 18, Number: 16
< 2024-07-26 00:36:19.320 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 39, Number: 16
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.320 Real path is '/sftpusername'
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.320 Trying to open directory "/sftpusername".
> 2024-07-26 00:36:19.320 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 18, Number: 263
< 2024-07-26 00:36:19.352 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 263
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.352 Getting current directory name.
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.430 Listing directory "/sftpusername".
> 2024-07-26 00:36:19.430 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 18, Number: 523
< 2024-07-26 00:36:19.477 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 523
> 2024-07-26 00:36:19.477 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 780
< 2024-07-26 00:36:19.508 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 1039, Number: 780
> 2024-07-26 00:36:19.508 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 1036
< 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 1036
< 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 Status code: 1
> 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 1284
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 ..;d;0;2024-04-12T16:18:28.000Z;4;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxr-xr-x;0
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 16072024;d;0;2024-07-16T11:40:12.000Z;4;"344815" [344815];"sftpaimsmember" [958];rwxrws---;0
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 18072024;d;0;2024-07-18T12:04:29.000Z;4;"344815" [344815];"sftpaimsmember" [958];rwxrws---;0
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 19072024;d;0;2024-07-19T11:43:05.000Z;4;"344815" [344815];"sftpaimsmember" [958];rwxrws---;0
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 22072024;d;0;2024-07-22T11:39:34.000Z;4;"344815" [344815];"sftpaimsmember" [958];rwxrws---;0
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 23072024;d;0;2024-07-23T11:34:56.000Z;4;"344815" [344815];"sftpaimsmember" [958];rwxrws---;0
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 24072024;d;0;2024-07-24T11:42:45.000Z;4;"344815" [344815];"sftpaimsmember" [958];rwxrws---;0
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.555 25072024;d;0;2024-07-25T11:43:47.000Z;4;"344815" [344815];"sftpaimsmember" [958];rwxrws---;0
. 2024-07-26 00:36:19.633 Startup conversation with host finished.

& here is the log file generated by the script using Session.SessionLogPath when GUI is open side by side:
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.793 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.793 WinSCP Version 5.21.1 (Build 12643 2022-06-24) (OS 10.0.17763 - Windows Server 2019 Standard)
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.793 Configuration: nul
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.793 Log level: Normal
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.793 Local account: somedomain\someuser
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.793 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.793 Process ID: 2088
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Ancestor processes: powershell, explorer, ...
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe" /xmllog="C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Temp\38\wscp3228.03C909A3.tmp" /xmlgroups /xmllogrequired /nointeractiveinput /stdout /stdin /dotnet=5.21.1  /ini=nul /log="D:\Schedulers\Powershell\BSEScriptSession25072024.log"  /console /consoleinstance=_12840_39236044_354
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Time zone: Current: GMT+5:30 (India Standard Time), No DST
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Login time: 26 July 2024 00:49:53
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: Retrospectively logging previous script records:
> 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: option batch on
< 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: batch           on        
< 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: reconnecttime   120       
> 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: option confirm off
< 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: confirm         off       
> 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: option reconnecttime 120
< 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: reconnecttime   120       
> 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: open sftp://sftpusername:***@11.222.333.44:5567 -hostkey="ssh-ed25519 255 DHhI/5fErnTc1txlbYDeBkRuhWkIMJl6axQRj4t/Xjy" -timeout=15 -rawsettings ProxyMethod="3" ProxyHost="10.26.46.92" ProxyPort="8080" ProxyUsername="someuser" ProxyPassword=***
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Session name: sftpusername@11.222.333.44 (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Host name: 11.222.333.44 (Port: 5567)
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 User name: sftpusername (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Tunnel: No
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Transfer Protocol: SFTP
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Disable Nagle: No
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Proxy: HTTP
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 HostName: 10.26.46.92 (Port: 8080); Username: someuser; Passwd: Yes
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Send buffer: 262144
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Compression: No
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Bypass authentication: No
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: Yes
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 GSSAPI: KEX: No; Forwarding: No; Libs: gssapi32,sspi,custom; Custom: 
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Ciphers: aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 KEX: ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Simple channel: Yes
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Shell: default
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 EOL: LF, UTF: Auto
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No; Exit code 1 is error: No
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 SFTP Bugs: Auto,Auto
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 SFTP Server: default
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 DST mode: Unix
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
< 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: Searching for host...
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Leaving host lookup to proxy of "11.222.333.44" (for SSH connection)
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Will use HTTP proxy at 10.26.46.92:8080 to connect to 11.222.333.44:5567
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Looking up host "10.26.46.92" for proxy
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Connecting to HTTP proxy at 10.26.46.92 port 8080
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Connecting to 10.26.46.92 port 8080
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Connected to 10.26.46.92
< 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Script: Connecting to host...
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.21.1
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.824 Connected to 10.26.46.92
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.870 Connected to remote host
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.870 Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.870 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.870 Have a known host key of type ssh-ed25519
. 2024-07-26 00:49:53.902 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.027 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/rsa-sha2-512/rsa-sha2-256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.027 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.027 ssh-ed25519 255 SHA256:DHhI/5fErnTc1txlbYDeBkRuhWkIMJl6axQRj4t/Xjs
< 2024-07-26 00:49:54.027 Script: Authenticating...
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.027 Host key matches configured key fingerprint
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.027 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] outbound encryption
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.027 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 outbound MAC algorithm
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.027 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] inbound encryption
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.027 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 inbound MAC algorithm
! 2024-07-26 00:49:54.121 Using username "sftpusername".
< 2024-07-26 00:49:54.121 Script: Using username "sftpusername".
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.183 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.183 Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.183 Trying gssapi-with-mic...
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.183 Attempting GSSAPI authentication
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.261 GSSAPI authentication request refused
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.261 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.261 Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.355 Prompt (keyboard interactive, "SSH server authentication", <no instructions>, "Password: ")
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.355 Using stored password.
< 2024-07-26 00:49:54.355 Script: Authenticating with pre-entered password.
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.480 Prompt (keyboard interactive, "SSH server authentication", <no instructions>, <no prompt>)
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.480 Ignoring empty SSH server authentication request
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.636 Access granted
. 2024-07-26 00:49:54.636 Opening main session channel
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.011 Opened main channel
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.136 Started a shell/command
< 2024-07-26 00:49:55.136 Script: Authenticated.
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.136 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.136 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.136 Doing startup conversation with host.
< 2024-07-26 00:49:55.136 Script: Starting the session...
> 2024-07-26 00:49:55.136 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 238, Number: -1
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Unknown server extension posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Supports statvfs@openssh.com extension version 2
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Unknown server extension fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Supports hardlink@openssh.com extension version 1
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Unknown server extension fsync@openssh.com="1"
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Unknown server extension lsetstat@openssh.com="1"
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Supports limits@openssh.com extension version 1
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Unknown server extension expand-path@openssh.com="1"
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Limiting packet size to OpenSSH sftp-server limit of 262148 bytes
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Getting current directory name.
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Getting real path for '.'
> 2024-07-26 00:49:55.214 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 10, Number: 16
< 2024-07-26 00:49:55.292 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 39, Number: 16
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.292 Real path is '/sftpusername'
. 2024-07-26 00:49:55.292 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2024-07-26 00:49:55.292 Script: Session started.
< 2024-07-26 00:49:55.292 Script: Active session: [1] sftpusername@11.222.333.44
> 2024-07-26 00:49:55.449 Script: pwd
< 2024-07-26 00:49:55.449 Script: /sftpusername


What do you mean by "When I am logged in to the SFTP server via WinSCP, the script runs fine".  Do you really mean that the script runs fine, when you are logged it in WinSCP GUI at the time you run the script?

Yes @MartinPrikryl - that is really what I mean!

Please post script session log file, when run standalone. And GUI and script log file when run side-by-side.

@MartinPrikryl I have added the script log file here. For both runs, one without being logged in and one with.

I've meant WinSCP logs.

@MartinPrikryl I have added the WinSCP logs here

@MartinPrikryl strangely, when the session on the GUI gets timed out, and I hit the reconnect button - I get the same error on GUI - Proxy error: Unable to parse auth header from HTTP proxy: authentication type 'NTLM' not supported

You still didn't post the three logs I've asked for.

@MartinPrikryl I do not understand how to collect the script session log file or the GUI log file apart from the one that I have already posted. Can you please help me point in the right direction so that I can share what you're asking for?

Use Session.SessionLogPath.

@MartinPrikryl, the log file generated using Session.SessionLogPath returned a log file that contains the same text as mentioned in the Update 2 of the original post. Am I missing something here?

What "text"? Do you mean the "log"? The .NET assembly Session.SessionLogPath cannot produce exactly the same log as the GUI log in your Update 2.

I have shared it in Update 3 in my post @MartinPrikryl

I have asked for three logs.

@MartinPrikryl I have added the other two logs as well.

@Martin
I was able to solve this problem by adding:
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic")

Thanks!

The sessions that work (GUI and the automated session that runs "along the GUI") have proxy credentials configured:
HostName: 10.26.46.92 (Port: 8080); Username: someuser; Passwd: Yes

The session that does not work, does not have credentials configured:
HostName: 10.26.46.92 (Port: 8080); Username: ; Passwd: No

So it actually does not look like you are running the same script (even the main SFTP username differs).

I am using the same script, but I am changing the credentials while posting here. The two logs were taken on different dates as you can see and hence there is an inconsistency.

You can see that I have passed the username and password in SessionOptions, in the code that I have posted here.

Well, then post consistent logs. Ideally unchanged. And if changed, then changed very carefully consistently.
